# How to auto close user account dropdown menu after few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

How I can close user account dropdown menu after few seconds after click on icon?
When I use these code setTimeout works only 1 times, when I refresh the browser.
Someone can help?

```
<body>
<nav>
    <div class="user">
        <h1>User email</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
        <div class="profile" onclick="menuToggle();">
            <i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size: 3em; color: #e0e1dd"></i>
        </div>
        
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">line 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">line 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">line 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<script>
    function menuToggle() {
        const toggleMenu = document.querySelector('.menu');
        toggleMenu.classList.toggle('active')
    }
    setTimeout(menuToggle, 4000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it using this code.

```js
const toggleMenu = document.querySelector('.menu');
function menuToggle() {
    toggleMenu.classList.toggle('active')
    setTimeout(removeToggle, 4000);
}
function removeToggle() {
    toggleMenu.classList.remove('active')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `setTimeout` inside the function `menuToggle`

```
function menuToggle() {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
      const toggleMenu = document.querySelector('.menu');
      toggleMenu.classList.toggle('active')
    }, 4000);
}
```

Comment: This will delay opening menu, not automatically close it.